# Public ip address of ec2 instance is None while the instance is initializing

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to get the public ip address of my ec2 instance after it has been created and is running using the following code:

```
instance = ec2_resource.create_instances(ImageId='ami-a0cfeed8', 
MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.micro', SecurityGroups= . 
['some_security_group'], KeyName='some_key')

instance[0].wait_until_running()
print(instance[0].public_ip_address)
```

But even though the public ip is visible in the aws console, the value that gets printed by the above code is `None`. If I try to print the value after all the status checks for the instance are complete, then it prints just fine.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to know that the status checks for the instance are still in progress i.e. it is in the initializing state?

Comment: Try calling [`.reload()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.reload) on the instance object, after `.wait_until_running()` then check the IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael-sqlbot! That worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

To take @Michael - sqlbot's answer and get it all in one place, here is how this code would work:

```
import boto3

# create the session and resource objects
boto3_session = boto3.Session(profile_name=some_profile_you_configured)
ec2_resource = boto3_session('ec2')

# create the instance
instance = ec2_resource.create_instances(ImageId='ami-a0cfeed8', 
MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.micro', SecurityGroups= . 
['some_security_group'], KeyName='some_key')

# use the boto3 waiter
instance[0].wait_until_running()

# reload the instance object
instance[0].reload()

public_ip = instance[0].public_ip_address

print(public_ip)
```

[boto3 Instance Documentation - reload()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.reload)